# Bootstrap 4, content with full width row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to developt this grid layout as you can see in the figure:

[image]

Basically there is an header, then there is the content within 3 columns, and the content is diviede by a sort of full width row with a middle text inside.

What would be the right bootstrap 4 structure to obtain this ?
I have tried to search the docs but found nothing.

I thought something like this:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col">content</div>
  <div class="col">content</div>
  <div class="col">content</div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="bg-dark py-4 my-4">
   <div class="container h-100">
      <div class="row h-100 align-items-center text-white">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
          <p>Middle Text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col">content</div>
  <div class="col">content</div>
  <div class="col">content</div>
 </div>
</div>

...etc...
```

But i don't know if opening and closing a div container for the content is good each time

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the code of what you achieve so far?

Comment: I think you can do what you are trying if you follow the bootstrap grid system https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ with a container, row and columns

Comment: @FlavioCaruso: hi flavio, i have added my solution but i don't know if it's good that's why i didn't posted it

Answer (score -1):

Here's some example using the bootstrap 4 [layout grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/), and the [spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/).

> Containers provide a means to center and horizontally pad your site’s
>   contents. Use .container for a responsive pixel width or
>   .container-fluid for width: 100% across all viewport and device sizes.

I add some [colors](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/colors/) to be more like your example. 
I recommend you to read the [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) 
 
It's very complete and will help you a lot with your next projects.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Bootstrap 4</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="pb-2 mt-4 mb-2 border-bottom bg-primary">
  <div class="container">
  <h1 class="ml-5 ">Site title</h1> 
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row container">
   <div class="col-1"></div>
   <div class="col-3 col-md m-1 bg-secondary">
    <br>
    <p>CONTENT</p>
    <br>
   </div>
   <div class="col-3 col-md m-1 bg-secondary">
    <br>
    <p>CONTENT</p>
    <br>
   </div>
   <div class="col-3 col-md m-1 bg-secondary">
    <br>
    <p>CONTENT</p>
    <br>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
  <div class="row container-fluid mt-3">
   <div class="col-12 col-md bg-light text-center">
    <p>MIDDLE TEXT</p>
   </div>
  </div>
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row container">
   <div class="col-1"></div>
   <div class="col-3 col-md m-1 bg-secondary">
    <br>
    <p>CONTENT</p>
    <br>
   </div>
   <div class="col-3 col-md m-1 bg-secondary">
    <br>
    <p>CONTENT</p>
    <br>
   </div>
   <div class="col-3 col-md m-1 bg-secondary">
    <br>
    <p>CONTENT</p>
    <br>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
  <div class="row container-fluid mt-3">
   <div class="col-12 col-md bg-light text-center">
    <p>MIDDLE TEXT</p>
   </div>
  </div>
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row container">
   <div class="col-1"></div>
   <div class="col-3 col-md m-1 bg-secondary">
    <br>
    <p>CONTENT</p>
    <br>
   </div>
   <div class="col-3 col-md m-1 bg-secondary">
    <br>
    <p>CONTENT</p>
    <br>
   </div>
   <div class="col-3 col-md m-1 bg-secondary">
    <br>
    <p>CONTENT</p>
    <br>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan, but if i run your solution it seems there is some spacing at the border of the middle backgrounds.. it should be full width

Comment: OK if you want the middle text be full width just let be outside the row.container div

Comment: I modify it so you can achieve it

Comment: i don't think you can have both row and container on the same div